# Migration Omitted One Field

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I did a Code Based migration with the following Context that I wanted to add to the Database:

```
 public class SignalRUserContext : DbContext
    {
        public SignalRUserContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SignalRUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SignalRConnection> Connections { get; set; }
    }

    public class SignalRUser
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SignalRConnection> Connections { get; set; }
    }

    public class SignalRConnection
    {
        [Key]
        public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public bool Connected { get; set; }
    }
```

I then did:

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Models.SignalRUserContext -MigrationsDirectory:SignalRMigrations -Force
```

and

```
Update-Database -configuration AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.SignalRMigrations.Configuration -Verbose
```

where

```
 public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Models.SignalRUserContext";
            MigrationsDirectory = @"SignalRMigrations";
        }
```

It created the tables SignalRUser and SignalRConnection but on SignalRUser it did not contin the Connections column. It left it out. If I leave out the [Key] on Connections it gives me an error that that there is no key defined for the Connections table. I don't need a key on this table. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your class, it is a reference to a collection of SignalRCOnnection objects.  A database has no concept of a collection field.  SignalRConnection table should get a FK pointing back to SignalRUser. Not sure how EF will automatically handle string as a primary key though. But by convention, your model design presumes that the "child" table will have an FK to SignalRUser and code first would would just create that field for you and use it when you query & update.
You shouldn't have to include the FK in your SignalRUser class. EF should be able to infer it in the database schema.